# Counting occurrences of word in a text file

Tags: python, word-count

I have to write a program that asks for a specific filename on the computer, counts the number of characters and words in the file and finally, the program should be able to count the amount of a word (from a user-input).

Comment: Please indent your code properly (I assume this is a copy and paste issue).

Comment: @Blincer while your edit makes the code look prettier, it only ends up adding more confusion to the already unclear question. Please consider revising or deleting your edit. Why would `numWords += len(words)` and `numChars += len(line)` be outside the `for line in fin:`? I would edit this myself, but I cannot decipher OP's intent.

Comment: Before the edition there was no indentation at all, so it was even less clear. If you see any problem I invite you to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You are finishing iterating over the file before you are attempting to count the occurrence of a specific word.  Reorganizing your code to put all of the counting in the file iterations should fix it.

```
numLines = 0 
numWords = 0
numChars = 0
count = 0

filename = input("Which file would you like to work with?: ")
freq_word = input("Which word would you like to find the frequency for?: ")

with open(filename, 'r') as fin:
    for line in fin: 
        words = line.split()
        for word in words:
            if word == freq_word:
                count +=1

        numWords += len(words)
        numChars += len(line)

print(filename, "contains: ", numChars, "characters and total amount of words is: ", numWords)
print(freq_word, "occurs ", count, "number of time")
```